# Spaces around hyphens

Tags: hyphenation

everyone - This question deals with spaces around hyphens, and I think this example may be an exception to the rule. Which is correct: **Post- Shoulder Surgery** or **Post-Shoulder Surgery** (note space after the hyphen in the first one)? My instincts tell me the first one is correct, but I would like to know the reason. I hope to be able to enlighten the people I work with.

Comment: Neither.  Both create the concept of a *post-shoulder*.  I think you mean *After shoulder surgery*.

Comment: Context is required - a sentence in which the phrase is used meaningfully. **Post** can be an adverb, a prefix, or a preposition (as well as a verb and noun...)

Comment: Are you saying Post-(Shoulder Surgery), as in *after someone has shoulder surgery*? The space isn't doing what you want there in modify the phrase *shoulder surgery*.

Comment: _I hope to be able to enlighten the people I work with._ We're really not here just so that you can win arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your input, everyone - "Post-Shoulder Surgery Expectations" is a heading on an ePub (which consists of a couple of short paragraphs). These are instructions sent to patients who have had shoulder surgery. I can't use "After" because "After Surgery Expectations" is already being used in another ePub, and we can't have any duplicate headings in our system. CJ Dennis: I would like to have an answer for my colleagues who will ask why we do/don't need that space. I prefer not to look like an idiot to the Dr's and clinicians I work with.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the title of, say, a section of instructions, and it means *After Shoulder Surgery*, you don't need any hyphen at all; you can use *post* as a preposition, just like *after*:

> Post Shoulder Surgery

Here is the OED's definition:

> **post**, *prep.*
>
> Subsequent to, later than; following, since.
>  <sub>1965 *Listener*
>   16 Sept. 432/3: *Der Ferne Klang* is post-Wagnerian, and post just
>   about everything else that was happening at the turn of the
>   century.</sub>
>  <sub>1979 *Daily Tel.* 19 July 21/4: Post the Geneva
>   meeting of Opec the OECD reckons that its 24 member countries..can
>   expect average economic growth of only two p.c. over the next 12
>   months.</sub>

(For that matter, why not use *after*?)

If this goes on to modify something else, you can use a "super hyphen" (a.k.a. an en dash):

> Post–Shoulder Surgery Checkup

Here's what *The Chicago Manual of Style* has to say about the super hyphen:

> Whereas a hyphen joins exactly two words, the en dash is intended to
>   signal a link across more than two. Because this editorial nicety will
>   almost certainly go unnoticed by the majority of readers, it should be
>   used sparingly, when a more elegant solution is unavailable. . . .
>
> ```
> the post–World War II years
> Chuck Berry–style lyrics
> country music–influenced lyrics (or lyrics influenced by country music)
> ```

Here are some more examples:

> En dashes connect the concepts in the following phrases: “Academy
>   Award–winning actor,” pre–Industrial Revolution technology,” “ex–vice
>   president,” and “non–United Nations action.”
>  <sub>Source: [En
>   Dashes Clarify Compound Phrasal
>   Adjectives](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/en-dashes-clarify-compound-phrasal-adjectives/)</sub>

Comment: One needs to stress that this is based on a single style guide. In the UK I had never heard of such a thing as a "super hyphen" before.

Comment: @WS2: It's not a single style guide—here are a couple more, for example: [From the Vault: Hyphens and En Dashes the MLA Way](https://style.mla.org/hyphens-and-en-dashes/) and [AMA Style Insider: En Dashes](https://amastyleinsider.com/2018/02/27/en-dashes/). And, as noted by CMOS above, just about no one anywhere has heard of the "editorial nicety" of using en dashes with compound adjectives.

Comment: We can't use en dashes for our literature, our software can't recognize them, and they convert to some sort of odd symbol.

Comment: @LynneMcClure: Ah, well, a hyphen it is then for *Post-Shoulder Surgery Expectations*. Or rewrite the title. Perhaps: *Expectations after Shoulder Surgery* (Plain language is good.)

Answer (score 0):

Post-Shoulder Surgery is perfectly fine. It passes the common-sense meaning test: what happens after surgery on the shoulder.

Comment: The reverse, surely? A hyphen joins two words to make  a compound (and doesn't use spaces). A dash (with spaces) marks a pause in a sentence.

Comment: I removed the reference to hyphens (the OP is using a dash). As for spaces on either side, that is a styling decision, not a grammar one.

Comment: Having read the question the answer and all the comments I'm still not clear what "post-shoulder surgery" is. It would seem to me that it must refer to what happens after shoulder surgery? So a word seems to be missing. Are we talking for example about "Post-shoulder-surgery physio"?

Comment: Needs two hyphens IMO.

Comment: You didn't address the question about spaces. Your comment mentions that that is a style issue, not grammar, but that's still not answering the question when it asked specifically about spaces not grammar.

Comment: Kate Bunting - what do you mean by "The reverse, surely?" WS2 - see my comment, above, to answer your question. Will Crawford - do you mean it should read "Post-Shoulder-Surgery Expectations"? nnnnnn - my question about spaces is, simply, is one required? If you need more context, see my previous answers/comments to the above group.